# Parsing nested array with connect.urlencoded()

Tags: express, connect, multidimensional-array

I have a web application that normally submits to a Spring MVC application. Posted form data looks something like this:

```
formBean[0].id="100"
formBean[0].name="Bill"
formBean[1].id="101"
formBean[1].name="Steve"
```

For testing/development purposes, I want to submit the same form to a node server running express (version 4). The connect bodyParser, configured as follows:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

does not parse the form data correctly. Dumping req.body to the console results in:

```
{ formBean: [ '0', '1' ] }
```

I get the expected result when I change the form field names so that the submitted data looks like this:

```
formBean[0][id]="100"
formBean[0][name]="Bill"
formBean[1][id]="101"
formBean[1][name]="Steve"
```

But, unfortunately, this doesn't work with our Spring MVC application.

Is there a way to configure connect.urlencoded to correctly parse the form data I am submitting? Is there a difference piece of middleware I should look at?

Answer (score 0):

Try

> { extended: false }

This forces the use of native queryString module in Node library

req.body should have => {"id":["100","101"],"name":["Bill","Steve"]}

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var parseUrlencoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}); //force the use of native queryString module in Node library
app.post(parseUrlencoded, function (request, response) {
    console.log('request.body ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
    .....
});
```